# Going to a new page instead of rendering component in <main/> using React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-v4

I am struggling with rendering the nested components in  when clicked on links in the drawer of material-ui-next. Following is my code for my Home component:

```
const Home = (props) => {
const { classes } = props;

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Drawer variant="permanent">
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
                <List component="nav">
                    {options.map(option => {
                        return (
                            <ListItem
                                key={option}
                                component={Link} to={`/${slugify(option, {lower: true})}`}
                                button>
                                <ListItemText primary={option} />
                            </ListItem>)
                    })}
                </List>
        </Drawer>
        <main className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/forecast' component={ContainerA} />
                    <Route path='/audience' component={ContainerB} />
                    <Route path='/adaptive-forecasting' component={ContainerC} />
                </Switch>
        </main>
    </div>
    )
};
```

As you can see, its a simple react-router 4 nesting here, as the child routes are specified in the home container instead of the Main.

But I am not able to figure out what is going wrong here.. can someone help?

**Update 1**

I am getting the following warning in the console, that definitely means something is wrong with the props I am passing:

```
browser.js:49 Warning: Material-UI: the value provided `undefined` is invalid
```

Comment: What I would do I would try to remove components one by one starting with `ListItemText` then `ListItem` to see which component is throwing an the error

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk i realized my mistake. If you see the code closely, I am rendering the routes at the root level without nesting them. I changed the path to '/home/forecast' and so on. And also did the same change in the ```<ListItem ... to={`/home/${slugify(option, {lower: true})}`} ```and it worked perfectly